# Angular dialogue box not resizing correctly

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

So I am using a angular dialogue box, however, setting custom size for this dialogue box ruins the format inside the box.

I have created a plunkr for this. http://plnkr.co/edit/yXf1kNMqhAdo3iM8dFBy

If you look at the "save" and "cancel" buttons, they appear somewhere near center of the page even though they are part of modal-footer.

Does anyone know how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

They are appearing to the right because `modal-footer` has a css property set as `text-align: right`.  They flow off of the plunker because `model-body` is being set as 800px in your code here: `modal.css("width",'800px');`.

You can add a style to override this if you want:

```
.modal-footer.left
{
  text-align:left;
}
```

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lYbW9Z?p=preview)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The modal-footer still isin't appearing at the bottom of the modal. I was not looking at aligning it left or right.